# ruby proc issue

Tags: ruby

Following code works

```
def lab
  Proc.new { return "foo1" }.call
  return "foo2"
end

puts lab #=> foo1
```

Following does NOT work. Why?. I get LocalJumpError

```
class Foo
  def self.doit(p)
    p.call
  end
end

p = Proc.new {
  return 'from block' 
}

a = Foo.doit(p)

puts a #=> LocalJumpError: unexpected return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the difference between [procs vs lambdas](http://samdanielson.com/2007/3/19/proc-new-vs-lambda-in-ruby) (Googling that will get you to a plentiful more of resources).

Basically, in the first case, your "return foo1" is returning **from lab**, and needs to be inside a context where to return.

You can achieve what you're trying to do using a lambda

```
p = lambda { return "from block" }
```

Also, note that you usually don't need a `return` statements in procs nor lambdas; they will return the last evaluated expression. So, it is equivalent to:

```
p = Proc.new{ "from block" }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get an expression from a proc, as well as doing

```
p = Proc.new{ "from block" }
```

like Chubas suggested, you can also use `next`, for example

```
p = Proc.new do
  next "lucky" if rand < 0.5 #Useful as a guard condition
  "unlucky"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically in the second case, you return from the Proc object before you make the call in Foo.doit(p).  Since p has already returned p.call has nothing to return to.